# How to create a textformfield with listTile that looks enabled

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I got a listtile that can use a function on tap and the textformfield.
How do I make it look like enabled but still prevent people from changing the value?

I tried FocusNode but it also disabled on onTap function.

```
ListTile(
    TextFormField(
    enabled: false,
    validator: (val) {
    if (val.isEmpty)
    return 'Please enter something';
    },
    controller: _controller,
    ),
onTap: () => _doSomething(),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `TextFormField` in an `IgnorePointer`:

```dart
ListTile(
  onTap: () => _doSomething(),
  title: IgnorePointer(
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      validator: (val) {
        if (val.isEmpty)
          return 'Please enter something';
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```